# Wrapper over a templated class with more than one template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, entity-component-system

I'm writting a thin wrapper over a class from a third-party library.

My code looks like this:

```cpp
template<typename TArg1, typename... TPack1, typename... TPack2>
class MyWrapper<TArg1, TPack1..., TPack2...> : protected ThirdParty<TArg1, TPack1..., TPack2...>
{
    // class is empty
};
```

Where the template parameters of my wrapper mimic the ones in the third party class.

However, my code doesn't compile. The first compiler error I get is:
`error C3856: 'MyWrapper': symbol is not a class template`

I think it's a problem of my code not giving enough context to the compiler for deducting the template parameter packs. Therefore, they're ambiguous at the `MyWrapper` level even if they aren't at the `ThirdParty` level. I've been trying to understand how `ThirdParty` guarantees it but I haven't so far (and I don't even know if that's the issue).

For full context, the specific case of this problem is me trying to wrap a struct from an ECS library called *entt*: `entt::basic_view`.

Comment: How should the compiler know where one pack ends and the next begins? Also: how do you use your class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't declare a [*class template*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template), but something like [*partial specilization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).
The correct way should be

```cpp
template <typename T>
class MyWrapper : protected ThirdParty<T>;
```

I don't use your template parameters since it contains 2 template parameter pack. The compiler can't know how to split the template arguments.

So I go to see the [source code](https://github.com/skypjack/entt/blob/master/src/entt/entity/view.hpp).

```cpp
template<typename, typename, typename, typename = void>
class basic_view;

template<typename Entity, typename... Component, typename... Exclude>
class basic_view<Entity, get_t<Component...>, exclude_t<Exclude...>> {
}; // get_t / exclude_t is a struct template type.
```

You can use multiple template parameter packs in the partial specialization.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename T, typename T, typename T = void>
class MyWrapper;  // without definition neither

template<typename Entity, typename... Component, typename... Exclude>
class MyWrapper<Entity, get_t<Component...>, exclude_t<Exclude...>>: protected basic_view<Entity, get_t<Component...>, exclude_t<Exclude...>> {
};
```

It works fine, see [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dd39rv9b9).